# Froala ImageUploadToS3 - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, froala

On their site, froala have the below;

> ```
>  $('.selector').froalaEditor({
>   imageUploadToS3: {
>     bucket: 'editor',
>     // Your bucket region.
>     region: 's3-us-east-1',
>     keyStart: 'uploads/',
>     callback: function (url, key) {
>       // The URL and Key returned from Amazon.
>       console.log (url);
>       console.log (key);
>     },
>     params: {
>       acl: 'public-read', // ACL according to Amazon Documentation.
>       AWSAccessKeyId: 'ACCESS_KEY', // Access Key from Amazon.
>       policy: 'POLICY_STRING', // Policy string computed in the backend.
>       signature: '', // Signature computed in the backend.
>     }
>   }
> });
> ```

I know how to generate all the `params`. But how do I implement this code in `AngularJS`?